# SharePoint List Error: “Value does not fall within the expected range” when I open Edit > Workflows

Tags: sharepoint

When I click on the Workflows from the Edit menu, it automatically displays “Value does not fall within the expected range” without me even starting a workflow.

All workflows were created from SharePoint Designer.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is rights issue. Your action attempts to get something that actually exists but currently logged in user does not have rights to access it and such type of error message is displayed.

Regards,

Azher Iqbal

Comment: Thank you for your response.

:)


even if the item is accessed by a site owner, it also gets the same error.

I'll try to see what I can do about the item privilege.